# Understanding the meaning of "multiple lifecycles application development"?

Tags: agile, java-ee, extreme-programming, sdlc

Some Agile job posts have a requirement "strong understanding of multiple lifecycles application development", what does it means ?

So my question would be: what's that field for, and what would I need to learn, knowing that I got Java EE experience and Agile more than 2 years.

Sorry if my question isn't constructed well, nor I putted some time searching the meaning :) my self, but all my research yielded job posts :D.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means they want you to have had experience of making several releases of an application i.e. you have know about taking things through from initial requirements to finished code for several releases.

Given that you have 2 years agile dev experience you should have this box ticked (assuming you made a few releases in those 2 years, if you didn't then you weren't really agile)

Comment: Does working in the Agile team in those applications releases counts as if you've that experience ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you think it does, you are the one who will have to defend your argument at interview.